# Connection Closed error for SQL Server 2008 through Glassfish 3.1 connection pool

Tags: sql-server-2008, jpa, glassfish, connection-pooling

In my new "hello world" EJB/JPA app using a GlassFish 3.1 connection pool for SQL Server 2008, I always get "Connection closed" errors on my first query, and frequently (though not always) when deploying the project. I must have something configured incorrectly, and I'm hoping someone can give me suggestions on where to look.

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) 64-bit
- Java 1.6.0_33 64-bit
- JPA Generic 2.0
- EclipseLink 2.4.0 - Juno
- Internal GlassFish 3.1.2.2
- Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server (sqljdbc4.jar)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SQLEXPRESS)

I'm using a connection pool (through JTA) that I created using the GlassFish admin page with the default settings. "Ping" succeeds. Here is the pool definition from domain.xml (I blanked out the password):

```
<jdbc-connection-pool driver-classname="" datasource-classname="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" description="" name="DemoDatabase">
    <property name="User" value="demo"></property>
    <property name="DatabaseName" value="demo"></property>
    <property name="ApplicationName" value="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"></property>
    <property name="LockTimeout" value="-1"></property>
    <property name="Password" value="******"></property>
    <property name="SendTimeAsDatetime" value="true"></property>
    <property name="PacketSize" value="8000"></property>
    <property name="SendStringParametersAsUnicode" value="true"></property>
    <property name="XopenStates" value="false"></property>
    <property name="TrustServerCertificate" value="false"></property>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:sqlserver://"></property>
    <property name="PortNumber" value="1433"></property>
    <property name="LoginTimeout" value="15"></property>
    <property name="ResponseBuffering" value="adaptive"></property>
    <property name="MultiSubnetFailover" value="false"></property>
    <property name="SelectMethod" value="direct"></property>
    <property name="LastUpdateCount" value="true"></property>
    <property name="WorkstationID" value="drizzle"></property>
    <property name="Encrypt" value="false"></property>
    <property name="ApplicationIntent" value="readwrite"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="DemoDatabase" description="" jndi-name="jdbc/DemoDatabase"></jdbc-resource>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="DemoEJB">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/DemoDatabase</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have also set up a similar GlassFish connection pool for MySQL. When I use that one, I do not get "Connection Closed" errors. I presume from this that the problem is in my SQL Server pool configuration.

Here is the error from the GlassFish log:

```
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [DemoEAR#Demo.war] at [Demo]
INFO: DemoEAR was successfully deployed in 1,066 milliseconds.
INFO: RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
INFO: RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
INFO: Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Entity1 sql="SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC").
INFO: RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
INFO: RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
INFO: Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Entity1 sql="SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC").
INFO: RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
INFO: RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
INFO: Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Entity1 sql="SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC").
INFO: RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
INFO: RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
INFO: Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Entity1 sql="SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC").
INFO: RAR7114: Unable to get ClientInfo for connection 
INFO: RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
INFO: Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Entity1 sql="SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC").
WARNING: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Entity1 sql="SELECT ID, VAL FROM entity1 ORDER BY ID ASC")
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1494)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:636)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1717)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:566)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:264)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:646)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2611)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2570)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:420)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1040)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1128)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1586)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5464)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1552)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1586)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5464)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1552)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1586)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5464)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1552)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.retryQuery(AbstractSession.java:1586)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.retryQuery(ClientSession.java:593)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.retryQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:5464)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1552)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
at com.centricsoftware.demo.module1.Module1.addEntity1(Module1.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
at $Proxy216.addEntity1(Unknown Source)
at com.centricsoftware.demo.module1.__EJB31_Generated__Module1__Intf____Bean__.addEntity1(Unknown Source)
at com.centricsoftware.demo.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolProxy.checkClosed(SQLServerConnectionPoolProxy.java:55)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolProxy.prepareStatement(SQLServerConnectionPoolProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.prepareStatement(ConnectionHolder.java:562)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:255)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareCachedStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:52)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnection.prepareCachedStatement(ManagedConnection.java:993)
at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionWrapper40.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper40.java:173)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1423)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:697)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:585)
... 98 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your database server running?

Maybe it is related to your LoginTimeout property, your login may take longer than this.  Try removing all of the properties except the required ones from your connection pool config.

It could also be a firewall, network or database issue timing out your connections.

You could also enable connection testing in your connection pool to validate connection before returning them.

You could also always use EclipseLink connection pooling instead, or try it to see if you get the same issue.

Also, include your persistence.xml.

Comment: I have added my persistence.xml.

Comment: My database is running - "Ping" works from the GlassFish connection-pool dialog, and I can send SQL to it using the Eclipse SQL Scrapbook view. I doubt it's a timeout, since I get the error in less than a second. I also doubt it's a firewall or connectivity problem since the database server is on my local machine. However, the most important info is that now, this morning, the problem has stopped happening. I haven't changed anything since I last tried it yesterday afternoon. Now I'm getting complaints about the sequence table, which I will post separately.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the .jar jdbc sqlserver driver in your glassfish server as folow: {installationPth}\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext

enjoy Kahoo:

(_/)
(='.'=)
(")_(")